# How to render JSX components in MDX in Remix

Tags: reactjs, remix.run

I am trying to build a blog using Remix and have my posts in MDX format, how can I render JSX components in my MDX
For example:

```
import LoginButton from '../../components/LoginButton.jsx'
# JSX Component rendered below
<LoginButton/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Example to be found in the docs: https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/guides/mdx#routes

Answer (score 0):

This might help: https://remix.run/docs/en/main/guides/mdx#advanced-example

When the file extension is .mdx you just need to import your components and use them among Markdown syntax. Just like your code.